# Passing mutex reference from main to a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, unique-lock

I need to work with the same `mutex` and `unique_lock` across the main function and class instances. However, I am having trouble assigning the `mutex`/`unique_lock` address to a class member variable (that is a `mutex&`).

This is what I have:

**Worker.h**

```
class Worker 
{
private:

    std::mutex &m_mu;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &locker;

public:

    void start(std::mutex &mu, std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &locker);

};
```

**Worker.cpp**

```
void Worker::start(std::mutex &mu, std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &locker)
{
    this->mu = mu; // error 
    this->locker = locker; // error
}
```

I tried doing `this->mu(mu)`; but that doesn't work either. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to change *what* a reference refers to.  `this->m_mu = mu;` is trying to copy the "value" of `mu` and assigning that "value" to whatever `this->m_mu` is currently referring to.

Comment: You do not need both mutex and the unique_lock as members of your class, this is redundant.

Comment: This smells bad. Most of the time a single class should be taking care of making itself threadsafe. I don't know why main would own a mutex or lock.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz this is not true. There are multitude of very reasonable cases when a single class should not make itself thread-safe.

Comment: @SergeyA I'll fed-ex you $5 if you show a listing where it makes sense to have main own a mutex and pass it around to other classes, rather than having any shared resource wrapped in a class that manages itself, while using proper OO, and C++

Comment: @ChristopherPisz you are not thinking out of the box. Simplest example will be when mutex is used a sort of gate - for example, to throttle some operation. I will not write code for this, so you can keep your $5.

Comment: @Sergey I have never seen this particular box in 35 years. I've seen people who wanted to make the box, but I offered them a steel chest instead. If you can't provide an example here or in private chat, then I fear all our words are wasted and noone will learn anything.

Comment: @Andrej you should not be sharing a `unique_lock` object between threads. That type is not thread-safe and not meant for concurrent access. The `mutex` is what you share, and each execution agent that wants to synchronise on that mutex creates its own `unique_lock` object to acquire and release the lock on the mutex.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz _"Most of the time a single class should be taking care of making itself threadsafe."_ [...] _"using proper OO, and C++"_ But what if you're not using an OO design? There's more than one way to design software.

Comment: @Jonathan In that case, we'd be talking about 'C' rather than 'C++', even if we opted to have that C use some C++ features. It's fairly accepted that C++, the language and the mindset, is object orientated, and embraces RAII. Neither 'C', the language,  nor the mindset (which is being alluded to here) is object orientated.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz that's utter nonsense! It's perfectly possible (and very popular) to write non-OO C++, while still using C++ features, not just using C. I think either you don't understand what OO means or you don't understand C++. RAII is not a feature of OO, for example. [Is C++ an Object-Oriented Language?](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#Object-Oriented-language) and [What is "multiparadigm programming"?](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#multiparadigm) and [Why C++ isn't just an Object-Oriented Programming Language](http://stroustrup.com/oopsla.pdf) go into more detail.

Comment: Strousup is right that the language itself does not force you to write OO code. He also said you are free to blow your leg off.  However, good practice, the C++ job market, and maintainability do have such requirements, whether you like them or not. Show me your mutex from main, non RAII, non OO code, and I'll show you bugtracker over 35 years of C++. Also, you can call passing a mutex from main to various classes, whatever you like. I'll call it unmaintainable, error prone, and undoubtedly the wrong way to do things, until shown a listing that proves otherwise.

Comment: Bottom line is that the mutex should live with the resource it protects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the mutex reference when you construct your class.

```
Worker::Worker(std::mutex &mu, std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &locker)
:m_mu(mu), locker(locker)
{}
```

That's the only place you can initialize a reference. Once it's constructed, you cannot change what it references.

Why do you need the locker? The mutex makes the synchronization, the lock is just a RAII object to ease acquiring the mutex.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to pass the *lock* object to the function. As long as the class is referring to the correct *mutex* you can lock the mutex inside the function like this:

```
class Worker
{
private:
    std::mutex& m_mu;

public:
    Worker(std::mutex& mu): m_mu(mu) {} // bind reference during initialization

    void start();

};

// Worker.cpp

void Worker::start()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_mu); // lock the shared resource

    // Do something with it here
}

int main()
{
    std::mutex mu;

    std::vector<Worker> workers(4, Worker(mu));

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is this approach going to work across multiple threads (of the same class type)? Also, I am getting a compile error: Worker::Worker(const Worker &)': attempting to reference a deleted function ----- when trying to initialize an array of Worker type 
std::vector<Worker> worker(threadsCountInt, Worker(std::ref(mu)));

Comment: @AndrejTkáč That should be fine as long as they lock the **same** *mutex*. I am not getting the error you are getting with my exact code. Did you do something different?

Comment: The error means he's trying to copy a `Worker` object, which won't work because the reference makes it non-copyable. I think there's a bigger design problem with the whole program.

Comment: I guess we don't need to use `std::ref` in this case, right? (Unless `std::thread` is used.)

Comment: @starriet Yes, you're right, `std::ref` was completely unnecessary. Now fixed.